# I want to disable Roo scaffolding

Tags: spring-roo

Because I have manually tuned my entities and controllers and view, I would like roo to change none of them. Nevertheless I would like roo to keep on scaffolding all new entities. How could I do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the @RooWebScaffold annotation in your entity by adding **update=false** attribute for it.

```
@RooWebScaffold(path = "<yourpath>", formBackingObject = <YourClass>.class, update=false)
```

This tells Roo not to scaffold and update views for the generated entity.

Cheers!!!

Comment: update in @RootWebScaffold: "Creates an update() method which allows alteration of an existing entity."

Comment: Adding `update=false` means Roo will remove the "update" (RequestMethod.PUT) controller methods and associated views.  The same can be applied with `create=false`, `delete=false`, etc.  It does not prevent updating your views/controllers like the question asks, it in fact will continuously delete them from your project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @RooEntity annotation from your entities and you should be good.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I remove @RooEntity annotation, roo just deletes lots of files and updates my views. I do not want that. I would just like roo to ignore those entities.

Comment: roo will delete all the scaffolding that it created while creating entity. I believe that is what your question was about. There is no side effect of Roo doing this. If you are observing any, please let us know here.

Comment: I see. I could see lot of files beeing deleted. Guess I need more experience. Thanks for the answer. I will test the process.

Answer (score 0):

> .aj are automanaged you must put your code in .java and if you need
>   change any method defined in .aj you must copy it in the .java an
>   change it there. STS and roo will delete it automatically from the
>   .aj.
>
> For the second question, yes you can do it. Roo only manage the file
>   views created by him, but only change all tags that have the "z"
>   parameter autogenerated by him. So if you change manually an
>   autogenerated view and you want thar roo does not change it you must
>   put in z parameter an undefined z value, for example (z=-1 or
>   z="user_managed") and roo will not change those tags.

source: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-126182.html