# How to disable web-tier auto update in roo(only update JPA entity)?

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, openjpa

In Roo, each time I modify an entity(especially relationships between entities), Roo will consequently update the fields/annotations/aspect which is convenient, but also update the web tier as well which made the jsp files looks really messy. I have to manually disable the 'render' to clear them up on the screen, but still remaining in the code.

So, is there any way I can prohibit Roo updating the web tier, let it only take care the plausible changes on JPA side?

Thanks in advance and have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answer for the below question.

[I want to disable Roo scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229229/i-want-to-disable-roo-scaffolding/6262048#6262048)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks bhagyas, I know there will be an expert help me finally :)